# error: ‘i’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working with boosts file system and i have following code to get the file list in root directory.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("/");
    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path())) 
        {
            cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

But i got following error in **gcc [ ubuntu ]**

```
error: ‘i’ does not name a type
     for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC doesn't enable C++11 mode automatically, and for type-deduction using `auto` you need C++11 mode (or later).

You can enable this with the `-std=c++11` option:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 your_source_file.cpp
```

Comment: But now i got following errors ` undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'` ?

Comment: @underscore Undefined references are *linker* errors, and it tells you that you don't link with a library that the code needs.

Answer (score 2):

This use of the keyword `auto` is only valid in c++11.  Are you using a complier compliant with that?  Prior to c++11, `auto` was a storage duration specifier. Your error looks like the complier is interpreting it the old way.